# What uses should I make of Entity Framework Entity Partial Classes?

Tags: c#, entity-framework, entity-framework-4, entity-framework-4.1

I'm working with EF 4.1 Database first. I was wondering what sort of things I may use Entity Partial Classes for. What would some examples of possible functionality I might want to add to partial classes. I'm just trying to understand if I should make my entities more capable or if I should be looking to add the functionality elsewhere? Are there good cases for things I may want to add to my entities?

For example I have an entity that has various child properties with start and end dates. These dates must not overlap. Is that something I should enforce on the parent entity?

---

Ok so suggestions seem to be validation and business logic. Additionally calculating things so that DB the doesn't have computed columns.

---

Should I be tying business logic to entity framework entities? What if I wanted to move away from EF?

Thanks

Graeme

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Validatable Objects and MetadataType attributes are used in the partial classes by frameworks such as MVC, for example.

**Here's an example of using the MetadataType attribute:**

```
[MetadataType(typeof(UserMetadata))]
public partial class User
{
    private class UserMetadata
    {
        [DisplayName("User Id")]
        public long UserId
        {
            get;
            set;
        }

        [DisplayName("User Name")]
        public string UserName
        {
            get;
            set;
        }
    }
}
```

When you use the MVC framework, any model that has these attributes will be read for purposes of automatic generation of label fields for the corresponding displays/editors.

**Example of using IValidatableObject**

```
public partial class Apple : IValidatableObject // Assume the Apple class has an IList<Color> property called AvailableColors
{
    public IEnumerable<ValidationResult> Validate(ValidationContext validationContext)
    {
        foreach (var color in this.AvailableColors)
        {
            if (color.Name == "Blue") // No blue apples, ever!
            {
                yield return new ValidationResult("You cannot have blue apples.");
            }
        }
    }
}
```

MVC will pick up on this IValidatableObject and ensure that any Apple that comes its way through it's validation step will never come in blue.

**EDIT**

As an example of your date range concern using IValidatableObject:

```
public partial class ObjectWithAStartAndEndDate : IValidatableObject
{
    public IEnumerable<ValidationResult> Validate(ValidationContext validationContext)
    {
        if (this.StartDate >= this.EndDate)
        {
            yield return new ValidationResult("Start and End dates cannot overlap.");
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: So mainly ensuring the entity is a valid thing?

Comment: Any type of business logic, really.  If you have one property that is required when another property of a different type is set and not required otherwise, you can do this by implementing the 'ghost methods' in a partial class.

Comment: I guess I'm using AutoMapper to make ViewModels and thet have the display name. However I suppose I need to enforce required etc on both the ViewModel and the Entity.

Comment: Great thanks. Just wondering if the dates of the child object themselves can't overlap. So parent entity has various child periods where would I check that the child periods themselves cannot span the same period?

Comment: Interestingly enough, I've had this issue and am working on a library to define entities with children that make sanity checks to avoid date range conflicts. I'll let you know when I put it on github.

Comment: Sounds good be really interested in seeing how you are doing it

Comment: @d_r_w how is your library progressing? Any advice on preventing date overlaps in EF

Answer (score 1):

I have used it to augment my generated classes with calculated values, when I'd rather not have the DB have calculated columns.